# Recovering from an Azure SQL Database failover

Tags: sql-server, azure, high-availability

I'm designing my Azure Website for High Availability.  In the interesting of doing so, I read the following: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-designing-cloud-solutions-for-disaster-recovery/#design-pattern-1-active-passive-deployment-for-cloud-disaster-recovery-with-a-co-located-database

In particular, I'm attempting to use Pattern #1.  In short, you:

- Establish your primary site and a backup site.
- Your backup site remains active, but never used directly while your primary site is functional.
- All database transactions are replicated from the primary to the secondary as they occur
- When a failover occurs, your traffic only hits your backup site.

My question is: after you failover, how would you return to your primary site?  If database transactions were written to your secondary database, they'd need to be written back to the primary.  Would you use "Geo Restore" (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-sql-database-geo-restore/) and restore your backup over your primary, then update the Azure Traffic Manager to begin using your primary location again?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand correctly, the 'syncing back' is done automatically.

[See here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/spotlight-on-new-capabilities-of-azure-sql-database-geo-replication/)

> When the failed primary recovers and is available again, the system will automatically mark it as a secondary and bring it up-to-date with the new primary.

And then, yes, I would update the Traffic Manager to route to the original primary again.